# Naming Color Variables in SASS

Tags: sass

When creating a color scheme in SASS what's the conventional variable names for defining colors?

I know using color names are bad. Such as:

```
$blue
$red
$green
```

But I've not seen an alternative. I'm struggling for variable names for colors on the site that convey meaning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my personal experience the most useful way to name colors is to do it in regards of the color's function, such as

- $background
- $contrast
- $text
- $aside
- $link

And so on. Of course which colors and name may depend on the design.

Then you may have different and exchangeable color schemes defined on different styles, such as:

- _dark_scheme.scss
- _light_scheme.scss
- _pastels.scss

The idea here, is that you can use the same color variables in your main stylesheets, and do not depend on specific colors.

Answer (score 13):

I found another idea in ["SASS & Color Variables" article](http://sachagreif.com/sass-color-variables/). The solution suggested **by Sacha Greif** is to use some variables to store descriptive color names, and some other to assign those colors to their functions:

```
 // first we set descriptive variables:
 $darkgrey: #333333;
 $blue: #001eff;

 // then we set functional variables:
 $text_color: $darkgrey;
 $link_color: $lightblue;
 $border_color: $lightblue;

 .myClass {
   color: $text_color;
   border-color: $border_color;
 }

 a {
   color: $link_color;
 }
```

I'm just beginning with SASS and don't know which approach is more practical, but I like the way it separates colors from their function.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20161012085308/http://sachagreif.com:80/sass-color-variables/

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of combining [generic to specific naming](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-name-your-sass-variables-modularly/) (good for code completion) and [description/functional naming](http://sachagreif.com/sass-color-variables/). So you have something like this:

```
 // Descriptive naming
 $color-gray-light: #f3f3f3;
 $color-gray-dark: #999999;
 $color-red: red;

 // Functional naming
 $link-color: $color-red;
 $link-border-color: $color-gray-light;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even create a mixin for greys (in the example RGBA is used for transparency, for example black on a red background would be more visible if it is 80% transparent black rather than dark grey).

```
@mixin grey($intensity: 0.5, $type: color) {
    #{$type}: rgba(black, $intensity);
}
.i-am-50-percent-gray {
    @include grey(0.5, color);
}
```

Give the result

```
.i-am-50-percent-gray {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```